# I am getting error when I try to run my flutter project

Tags: flutter

When I try to run my flutter project I get this error below when it's compiling

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my output with `flutter doctor` command

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 15.9.47)
    X Visual Studio 2019 or later is required.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

I have run `flutter upgrade`, and still get same issue, before downgrading to my present version

I also deleted pubspec.lock file and run `flutter pub get`, still getting same error.

Please how can I solve this error, I have been on it for so long

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter clean ,
close IDE ,
restart pc,
open ide ,
run flutter pub get ,
run flutter run,

Comment: I have tried that as well,  But still getting the same error